# adding list elements to pandas dataframe at row level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which returns 3 elements list which I have to enter in pandas dataframe. Function takes `names` and recommend 3 similar names in list which I have to map against it.

```
      names             
      a       
      b
      c
```

my desired dataframe would be

```
      names     recommendations             
      a         d
      a         e
      a         f  
      b         x
      b         y
      b         z
      c         p 
      c         q
      c         r
```

Function returns following output

```
 def get_recommendations(names, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):

     idx = indices[names]
     sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
     sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
     sim_scores = sim_scores[1:6]
     movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
     return list(df['names'].iloc[names_indices])

 get_recommendations('a') = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

I am doing following thing in `Pandas`, but this does not work.

```
 df['recommendations'] = df.apply(lambda row : get_recommendations(row['names']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new column by using `apply` and `function`

Then use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df["recommendations"] = df["names"].apply(get_recommendations)

df = df.explode("recommendations")

print(df)
```

Comment: getting following error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: on which line? apply or explode?

Comment: when I do apply

Comment: @AkshayNavrekar I have added my function in question

Comment: This is the error I am getting `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @Neil add complete error message in your question. It's really difficult to say by looking at this only